# How can I override admin create order controller?

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, controllers

I am trying to override adminhtml_sales_order_create controller. I have created a small module app/code/local/Akina/Sales/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Akina_Sales>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </Akina_Sales>
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <sales before="Mage_Adminhtml">Akina_Sales_Adminhtml</sales> 
                    </modules>
               </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

and created controller file as

app/code/local/Akina/Sales/controllers/Adminhtml/Sales/order/CreateorderController.php

```
<?php
require_once 'Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/CreateController.php';
class Akina_Sales_Adminhtml_sales_Order_CreateorderController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController
{
    public function saveAction()
    {
        echo "test";die;
    }
}
```

My module declaration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Akina_Sales>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Akina_Sales>
    </modules>
</config>
```

I am unable to override this controller, where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this in the module declaration file

```
<depends>
    <Mage_Adminhtml />
</depends>
```

right below `<codePool>local</codePool>`.

place your new controller in `app/code/local/Akina/Sales/controllers/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/CreateController.php`
and name the controller class `Akina_Sales_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController`.
be careful at uppercase letters.

Comment: ' Not working '

Answer (score 0):

Along with the Marius answer

In your config.xml change

```
<adminhtml>
     <args>
       <modules>
          <sales before="Mage_Adminhtml">Akina_Sales_Adminhtml</sales> 
       </modules>
    </args>
</adminhtml>
```

To

```
<adminhtml>
     <args>
       <modules>
          <Akina_Sales_Adminhtml before="Mage_Adminhtml">Akina_Sales_Adminhtml</Akina_Sales_Adminhtml> 
       </modules>
    </args>
</adminhtml>
```

Comment: I have already done change but is not working

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
<adminhtml>
     <args>
       <modules>
          <Akina_Sales before="Mage_Adminhtml">Akina_Sales_Adminhtml</Akina_Sales> 
       </modules>
    </args>
</adminhtml>
```

Instead of

```
<adminhtml>
     <args>
       <modules>
          <sales before="Mage_Adminhtml">Akina_Sales_Adminhtml</sales> 
       </modules>
    </args>
</adminhtml>
```